# How to disable the submit button for a form of MC?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to do a MC question with radio button. Each question is required to be choice one answer only. Each question has three choices. I want to check whether the user answers every question. If yes, able the submit button. If no, disable the submit button.
Here is my code:

```
<form name ='form' method ='post' action ='getResult' id ='form'>
      Q1. XXXXXXXXXX
      <br>
      <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='option_1' value= '1'> A1 <br>
      <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='option_1' value= '2'> A2 <br>
      <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='option_1' value= '3'> A3 <br>
      Q2. XXXXXXXXXX
      <br>
      <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='option_2' value= '1'> A1 <br>
      <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='option_2' value= '2'> A2 <br>
      <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='option_2' value= '3'> A3 <br>

      <Input type = 'Reset' Name = 'Reset' VALUE = 'Reset'>
      <Input type = 'Submit' Name = 'submitorder' VALUE = 'Submit' id='submitorder' disabled='disabled'>

                </form>
```

I just make it simple on the content of the question, answer and the value of button.

Comment: Use the jquery-validate plugin. http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Ya post rendered HTML, not the php code. BTW, task you are looking for is really basic, just return true if check is ok, otherwise return false or prevent default behaviour of the form's submit handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(function(){
      $("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
      the_value = getChecklistItems();      
      if(the_value=="2")  
         $("#submitorder").removeAttr('disabled');
      else
         $("#submitorder").prop('disabled',true);  
    });
      $("#reset").click(function(){
          $("#submitorder").prop('disabled',true);
      });
  });

function getChecklistItems() {
    var count=0;
    var result = 
        $("input:radio:checked").get();

    var columns = $.map(result, function(element) {
        count=count+1;
    });

    return count;
}
```

HTML Change, assign some id to reset button like as below:

```
 <Input type = 'Reset' Name = 'Reset' id="reset" VALUE = 'Reset'>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5CDR3/2/)

Comment: thank you for you answer, but i don't want to pop up a window when answer every question, also, when i answer all the questions and click the reset button, the submit still be enabled